# Duplicate Meta Descriptions for Paginated Content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, meta-description

How is it in 2019 with duplicate meta-description in case of large overview pages with a lot of pages (pagination).
I researched and found inconsitent guidance to that topic.

Comment: How is what? I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you clarify what kind of information you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Write a different title + meta description for each page.
2. Don't paginate at all, Google loves long pages.

PS: Some might say "noindex, follow" the paginated pages but i think that's a bad idea since 1. You want them to rank and 2. Google said they will start nofollowing pages with noindex.

Comment: I aggree with "don't paginate".    Or if you do, put 100 items on the first page and `noindex` subsequent pages.   Pagination does nothing for SEO (except maybe hurt it) and 98% of users never use it.